What does this prayer flag say?
I don't know much about Buddhism. Sorry if this is off-topic.
Where I live, Buddhism is rather uncommon, but in recent years, Tibetan prayer flags have become more and more widespread. These ones were installed close to my workplace, and made me curious.
For what I've learned, these are lungdhar or lung ta, and the design involves the lung ta horse in the center, as well as the "four mythical animals, tiger, snow lion, dragon and Garuda" in each corner.
But there is one thing I have found little information about, and it involves the text. I've read they are supposed to be mantras, but I have a (composite) question about the meaning:
What exactly do they say? Is the text always the same, or it varies from one to the other? If the latter is the case, I'm particularly interested in this specific flag. I believe they are written in Tibetan script, but Google translate wasn't able to tell the language or give a translation.
I'm sorry for the low quality of the photo. I know I just cut the text, but I hope it's enough to identify at least some of the general meaning (if the text is different from flag to flag).

